# AJAX asp Web Forms search in grid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I found implementation of my problem on a side but i dont know why it isn't working. When i put some value into textbox it should do me a postback but it does not.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txt" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txt_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView2">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" ItemStyle-Font-Size="10px" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="regon" HeaderText="Regon" SortExpression="regon" ItemStyle-Font-Size="10px" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="nip" HeaderText="NIP" SortExpression="nip" ItemStyle-Font-Size="10px" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

And code behind :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             txt.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'txt\',\'\')', 0)");
             string SelectCommand = "SELECT * " +
                 "  FROM client_inf WHERE amount > 1000";
             conn.Open();
             OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(SelectCommand, conn);
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             da.Fill(ds);
             GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
             GridView1.DataBind();
             conn.Close();
        }
    }
     protected void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt.Text != "")
        {
            string SelectCommand = "SELECT * " +
                 "  FROM client_inf WHERE client_name Like '" + txt.Text + "%'"
             conn.Open();
             OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(SelectCommand, conn);
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

http://www.infosearchshop.com/21-gridview-search-as-you-type-with-ajax

Comment: please change `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txt" />` to  `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox1" />` TextBox  's id don't match .

Answer (score 0):

TextBox 's id and **GridView's ID**  don't match .

```
<div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txt" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txt_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" ItemStyle-Font-Size="10px" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="regon" HeaderText="Regon" SortExpression="regon" ItemStyle-Font-Size="10px" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="nip" HeaderText="NIP" SortExpression="nip" ItemStyle-Font-Size="10px" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                txt.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'txt\',\'\')', 0)");
                GridView1.DataSource = GetDataSource();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        private DataTable GetDataSource()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("regon", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("nip", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add("Name-1", "regon-1", "nip-1");
            dt.Rows.Add("Name-2", "regon-1", "nip-1");
            dt.Rows.Add("Name-3", "regon-1", "nip-1");
            dt.Rows.Add("Name-4", "regon-1", "nip-1");
            dt.Rows.Add("Name-5", "regon-1", "nip-1");
            dt.Rows.Add("Name-6", "regon-1", "nip-1");
            dt.Rows.Add("Name-7", "regon-1", "nip-1");
            return dt;
        }
        protected void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt.Text != "")
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = GetDataSource();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to update the `AsyncPostBackTrigger` as follow to match the ID of the `textbox` = TextBox1 with the `AutoPostBack` reference but the control needs to be outside the `UpdatePanel`

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="TextBox1" EventName ="TextChanged" />
```

I would also suggest trying to use `PostBackTrigger` instead. This is mostly used for controls inside the `UpdatePanel` that makes a full post back

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox1" />
```

Comment: `PostBackTrigger` works well but i dont know why that first `AsyncPostBackTrigger` does not

Comment: `PostBackTrigger` still reload my all page

Comment: From prior experience that is the trade-off for the AutoPostBack to work. I don't know what the fix is for this behavior.